# ASP.NET : Filter unique rows from Data table

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

Hi i am using data table in asp.net. I am not able to get how can we filter unique data from data table .

Problem is describe below

```
Data Table:
Consumer No Date             Value
ABC001           1st Aug 09 1
ABC001           1st Aug 09 2
ABC001           2nd Aug 09 1
XYZ001           1st Aug 09 1
XYZ002           1st Aug 09 1
XYZ002           1st Aug 09 2
```

I would like following output based upon filter applied over first and second column. In output we can see that there is unique combination of first and second column.

```
Consumer No Date             
ABC001           1st Aug 09 
ABC001           2nd Aug 09 
XYZ001           1st Aug 09 
XYZ002           1st Aug 09
```

How can i apply filter on data table?

Comment: cant you just loop over it, removing the duplicates?

Comment: Hi,

No need to go in loop. Please read phoenix/ Preets reply. It helps me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
yourdataset.Tables["TableName"].DefaultView.ToTable(true,"disticecolumn");
```

> Creates and returns a new  DataTable
>   based on rows in an existing 
>   DataView.

true in the .ToTable method specifies that returned  DataTable contains rows that have distinct values for all its columns.

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx) article

***Edit:***

It would be easier to do this from a database where you can use the '**distinct**' keyword.

Answer (score 3):

There is apparently no way you can apply a DISTINCT filter on the Select() method of the DataTable.

However, you can create a new DataTable using the following line of code:

```
DataTable filterTable = yourDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable("TargetTable", true, "Consumer", "No", "Date");
```

This should return distinct rows, that meet your requirement!

Credit to [DevPinoy.org](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2008/02/07/how-to-get-the-distinct-rows-in-a-datatable-or-dataview.aspx) !

Comment: But of course ! My Google search just happened to land on DevPinoy!

Comment: Hi my thanks to you both Phoenix and Preets. Also my credit goes to both of you because you become path for my destination. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
private static DataTable SelectDistinct(DataTable SourceTable, params string[] FieldNames)
{
     object[] lastValues;
     DataTable newTable;
     DataRow[] orderedRows;

     if (FieldNames == null || FieldNames.Length == 0)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("FieldNames");

     lastValues = new object[FieldNames.Length];
     newTable = new DataTable();

     foreach (string fieldName in FieldNames)
          newTable.Columns.Add(fieldName, SourceTable.Columns[fieldName].DataType);

     orderedRows = SourceTable.Select("", string.Join(", ", FieldNames));

     foreach (DataRow row in orderedRows)
     {
          if (!fieldValuesAreEqual(lastValues, row, FieldNames))
          {
               newTable.Rows.Add(createRowClone(row, newTable.NewRow(), FieldNames));

               setLastValues(lastValues, row, FieldNames);
          }
     }

     return newTable;
}

private static bool fieldValuesAreEqual(object[] lastValues, DataRow currentRow, string[] fieldNames)
{
     bool areEqual = true;

     for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.Length; i++)
     {
          if (lastValues[i] == null || !lastValues[i].Equals(currentRow[fieldNames[i]]))
          {
               areEqual = false;
               break;
          }
     }

     return areEqual;
}

private static DataRow createRowClone(DataRow sourceRow, DataRow newRow, string[] fieldNames)
{
     foreach (string field in fieldNames)
          newRow[field] = sourceRow[field];

     return newRow;
}

private static void setLastValues(object[] lastValues, DataRow sourceRow, string[] fieldNames)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.Length; i++)
          lastValues[i] = sourceRow[fieldNames[i]];
}
```

source: http://weblogs.asp.net/eporter/archive/2005/02/10/370548.aspx

Comment: Thanks ala,

Reply of phoenix and Preets are also great.
Using one line statement we can get output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do something like this :

```
var resultSet = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable() 
    select r["ConsumerNo"]).Distinct().ToList();
```

see the post [Using LINQ to manipulate DataTable's data](http://aspdotnetcode.source-of-humor.com/Articles/LINQ/HowToUseLINQtoQueryDataTableInCSahrpSyntax.aspx)

best Rgds

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable filteredTable = yourDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable("TargetTable", true, "Consumer", "No", "Date");
```

this code fulfilled my requirement....Thanks! A lot!